# Multiselection Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, multi-select

I am new in Android development. I have MultiselectionListview in my app.I want to delete all the items selected, But for it i have to call a function from Sqlite Db.I have to pass selected item positions in the form of array. I am getting position as follows :

```
SparseBooleanArray checked = lv_del.getCheckedItemPositions();
    for (int i= 0; i<=checked.size();i++)
    {
        int[] posArr = new int[checked.size()];
        // Item position in adapter

         int position = checked.keyAt(i);
         if(checked.valueAt(i))
         {
             posArr  [i] = (int) adapter.getItemId(position);
         }
    }

}
```

but its not working, how can i pass selected items positions via array ?? 
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Brother Please specify your problem more clearly

Comment: What exactly is your issue? It looks to me like `posArr` will end up containing the `itemId` for all the checked items in your list. Is this not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an additional button outside the listview as an **ok** button.And write the code for creating the list of items using position array and call the delete function with that list  in the listener of **ok** button.